# How is the loss value calculated in order to compute the gradient?

Tags: deep-learning, gradient-descent

The gradient descent step is the following

\begin{align}
\mathbf{W}_i = \mathbf{W}_{i-1} - \alpha * \nabla L(\mathbf{W}_{i-1})
\end{align}

were $L(\mathbf{W}_{i-1})$ is the loss value, $\alpha$ the learning rate and $\nabla L(\mathbf{W}_{i-1})$ the gradient of the loss.

So, how do we get to the $L(\mathbf{W}_{i-1})$ to calculate the gradient of $L(\mathbf{W}_{i-1})$? As an example, we can initialize the set of $\mathbf{W}$ to 0.5. How can you explain it to me?

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate the gradient of $f$ or how to calculate the loss value itself?

Comment: Wow, Thanks for your edition. Before I can to calculate the gradient of f(W), I should have the f function. So, how can I have the f function at the first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, $L$ is the loss (or cost) function, which can be, for example, the [mean squared error (MSE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) or the cross-entropy, depending on the problem you want to solve. Given one training example $(\mathbf{x}_i, y_i) \in D$, where $\mathbf{x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is the input (for example, an image) and $y_i \in \mathbb{R}$ can either be a label (aka class) or a numerical value, and $D$ is your training dataset, then the [MSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) is defined as follows

$$L(\mathbf{W}) = \frac{1}{2} \left(f(\mathbf{x}_i) - y_i \right)^2,$$

where $f(\mathbf{x}_i) \in \mathbb{R}$ is the output of the neural network $f$ given the input $\mathbf{x}_i$.

If you have a mini-batch of $M$ training examples $\{(\mathbf{x}_i, y_i) \}_{i=1}^M$, then the loss will be an average of the MSE for each training example. For more info, have a look at this answer https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/11675/2444. The https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/8985/2444 may also be useful.

See the article [Loss and Loss Functions for Training Deep Learning Neural Networks](https://machinelearningmastery.com/loss-and-loss-functions-for-training-deep-learning-neural-networks/) for more info regarding different losses used in deep learning and how to choose the appropriate loss for your problem.

Comment: Is that true to say : L(w) = 1/2 * (f(x,w) - y)**2 ?

Comment: I did not get my answer completely however, your answer was very helpful.
You said in this answer: (
https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/11667/is-back-propagation-applied-for-each-data-point-or-for-a-batch-of-data-points/11675#11675 )
"For simplicity, assume that we are able to calculate the gradient of L, that is, delat(L)". So, how can I calculate the gradient of L function according to W set, because I need to update my W set. I mean that, do we have such a function like f(x) = 2x and then calculate the L(w)=1/2*(2x-y)**2 and delta(L) = 2*(2x-y)?

Comment: $f(x, w)$ or $f(x)$ are "just" notations, in the sense that $w$ is clearly a parameter (or weight) of the neural network $x$, but $w$ is not an input to the neural network: $x$ is the input! The way you calculate the gradient of $L$ with respect to any of the parameters is with **back-propagation** and it depends on the architecture of the neural network and the loss function you choose. To understand back-propagation, you need to understand the basics of calculus.

Comment: Thanks and I got the point :
https://towardsdatascience.com/linear-regression-using-gradient-descent-97a6c8700931